# Add additional values to object fields in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I search the collection for certain values according to the conditions:

In different situations, I have different types of Moments (`M`) and shear forces (`T`).

By default, `T` and `M` are the defaults for the Double type

I have created general fields for `M` and `T` in the object and would like to insert specific values during the search

```
var temp = dbConnectors.FB_700_200.Where(c => c.Height == h_db1 && c.Length == len && c.T_80_PLUS >= vrd_ob && c.M_80_MINUS >= mrd_db).ToList();

foreach (var item in temp)
{
    item.T = item.T_80_PLUS; // it is different in different situations
    item.M = item.M_80_MINUS; // it is different in different situations
}

results.AddRange(temp);
```

Is it possible to modify LINQ so that what is here is done in:

```
results.AddRange(dbConnectors.FB_700_200.Where...);
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter This fragment I added works, but the question is whether it can be optimized and done in 1 line. I have a lot of different conditions to do and that would simplify things

Comment: @TimSchmelter The same is not always assigned. For `item.T = item.T_80_PLUS;` sometimes it is `T_80_PLUS` and other times it is `T_120_PLUS` and another time it may be `T_80_MINUS`. Depending on the situation, I refer to a different field in the object

Comment: @TimSchmelter Only 1 situation is shown here. And I have many more

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would have to create 16 methods for each of the possible situations. And this solution does not simplify the matter too much

Comment: @TimSchmelter I added an answer about what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new constructor based on an existing object like below:

```
public NewConnector(NewConnector c, double Tn, double Mn)
{
    Id = c.Id;
    Name = c.Name;
    // other fields in the object

    T = Tn;
    M = Mn;
}
```

And finally, I can make a simple record:

```
results.AddRange(BalconyViewModel.Instance.dbConnectors.FB_700_200
    .Where(c => c.Height == h_db1 && c.Length == len && c.T_80_PLUS >= vrd_ob && c.M_80_MINUS >= mrd_db)
    .Select(c => new NewConnector(c, c.T_80_PLUS, c.M_80_MINUS)));
```

This solution simplifies to one line

Answer (score 0):

If your class has a generic field, you can use the following query.

```
var temp = dbConnectors.FB_700_200.Where(c => c.Height == h_db1 && c.Length == len && c.T_80_PLUS >= vrd_ob && c.M_80_MINUS >= mrd_db)
         .Select(a => new FB_700_200() 
         {
             ID = a.ID,
             //.......................
             T = a.T_80_PLUS,
             M = a.M_80_MINUS
         })
         .ToList();
results.AddRange(temp);
```